# RTP packets detected as UDP

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, webrtc, kurento, sdp

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
WebRTC endpoint > RTP Endpoint > ffmpeg > RTMP server.
```

This is what my SDP file looks like.

```
var cm_offer = "v=0\n" +
              "o=- 3641290734 3641290734 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\n" +
              "s=nginx\n" +
              "c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1\n" +
              "t=0 0\n" +
              "m=audio 60820 RTP/AVP 0\n" +
              "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\n" +
              "a=recvonly\n" +
              "m=video 59618 RTP/AVP 101\n" +
              "a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000\n" +
              "a=recvonly\n";
```

What's happening is that wireshark can detect the incoming packets at port 59618, but not as RTP packets but UDP packets. I am trying to capture the packets using ffmpeg with the following command:

```
ubuntu@ip-132-31-40-100:~$ ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:59618 -vcodec copy stream.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2017-01-22-f1214ad Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc
  libavutil      55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 63.100 / 57. 63.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 69.100 /  6. 69.100
  libavresample   3.  2.  0 /  3.  2.  0
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
```

All I get is a blinking cursor and The stream.mp4 file is not written to disk after I exit (ctrl+c).

So can you help me figure out:

1. why wireshark cannot detect the packets as RTP (I suspect it has something to do with SDP)
2. How to handle SDP answer when the RTP endpoint is pushing to ffmpeg which doesn't send an answer back.

Here is the entire code (hello world tutorial modified)

```
/*
     * (C) Copyright 2014-2015 Kurento (http://kurento.org/)
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    function getopts(args, opts)
    {
      var result = opts.default || {};
      args.replace(
          new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
          function($0, $1, $2, $3) { result[$1] = decodeURI($3); });

      return result;
    };

    var args = getopts(location.search,
    {
      default:
      {
        ws_uri: 'wss://' + location.hostname + ':8433/kurento',
        ice_servers: undefined
      }
    });

    function setIceCandidateCallbacks(webRtcPeer, webRtcEp, onerror)
    {
      webRtcPeer.on('icecandidate', function(candidate) {
        console.log("Local candidate:",candidate);

        candidate = kurentoClient.getComplexType('IceCandidate')(candidate);

        webRtcEp.addIceCandidate(candidate, onerror)
      });

      webRtcEp.on('OnIceCandidate', function(event) {
        var candidate = event.candidate;

        console.log("Remote candidate:",candidate);

        webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate(candidate, onerror);
      });
    }


    function setIceCandidateCallbacks2(webRtcPeer, rtpEp, onerror)
    {
      webRtcPeer.on('icecandidate', function(candidate) {
        console.log("Localr candidate:",candidate);

        candidate = kurentoClient.getComplexType('IceCandidate')(candidate);

        rtpEp.addIceCandidate(candidate, onerror)
      });
    }


    window.addEventListener('load', function()
    {
      console = new Console();

      var webRtcPeer;
      var pipeline;
      var webRtcEpt;

      var videoInput = document.getElementById('videoInput');
      var videoOutput = document.getElementById('videoOutput');

      var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
      var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");

      startButton.addEventListener("click", function()
      {
        showSpinner(videoInput, videoOutput);

        var options = {
          localVideo: videoInput,
          remoteVideo: videoOutput
        };


        if (args.ice_servers) {
         console.log("Use ICE servers: " + args.ice_servers);
         options.configuration = {
           iceServers : JSON.parse(args.ice_servers)
         };
        } else {
         console.log("Use freeice")
        }

        webRtcPeer = kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options, function(error)
        {
          if(error) return onError(error)

          this.generateOffer(onOffer)
        });

        function onOffer(error, sdpOffer)
        {
          if(error) return onError(error)

          kurentoClient(args.ws_uri, function(error, client)
          {
            if(error) return onError(error);

            client.create("MediaPipeline", function(error, _pipeline)
            {
              if(error) return onError(error);

              pipeline = _pipeline;

              pipeline.create("WebRtcEndpoint", function(error, webRtc){
                if(error) return onError(error);

                webRtcEpt = webRtc;

                setIceCandidateCallbacks(webRtcPeer, webRtc, onError)

                webRtc.processOffer(sdpOffer, function(error, sdpAnswer){
                  if(error) return onError(error);

                  webRtcPeer.processAnswer(sdpAnswer, onError);
                });
                webRtc.gatherCandidates(onError);

                webRtc.connect(webRtc, function(error){
                  if(error) return onError(error);

                  console.log("Loopback established");
                });
              });



            pipeline.create("RtpEndpoint", function(error, rtp){
                if(error) return onError(error);

                //setIceCandidateCallbacks2(webRtcPeer, rtp, onError)


                var cm_offer = "v=0\n" +
                      "o=- 3641290734 3641290734 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\n" +
                      "s=nginx\n" +
                      "c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1\n" +
                      "t=0 0\n" +
                      "m=audio 60820 RTP/AVP 0\n" +
                      "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\n" +
                      "a=recvonly\n" +
                      "m=video 59618 RTP/AVP 101\n" +
                      "a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000\n" +
                      "a=recvonly\n";



                rtp.processOffer(cm_offer, function(error, cm_sdpAnswer){
                  if(error) return onError(error);

                  //webRtcPeer.processAnswer(cm_sdpAnswer, onError);
                });
                //rtp.gatherCandidates(onError);

                webRtcEpt.connect(rtp, function(error){
                  if(error) return onError(error);

                  console.log("RTP endpoint connected to webRTC");
                });
              });









            });
          });
        }
      });
      stopButton.addEventListener("click", stop);


      function stop() {
        if (webRtcPeer) {
          webRtcPeer.dispose();
          webRtcPeer = null;
        }

        if(pipeline){
          pipeline.release();
          pipeline = null;
        }

        hideSpinner(videoInput, videoOutput);
      }

      function onError(error) {
        if(error)
        {
          console.error(error);
          stop();
        }
      }
    })


    function showSpinner() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arguments[i].poster = 'img/transparent-1px.png';
        arguments[i].style.background = "center transparent url('img/spinner.gif') no-repeat";
      }
    }

    function hideSpinner() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arguments[i].src = '';
        arguments[i].poster = 'img/webrtc.png';
        arguments[i].style.background = '';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Lightbox utility (to display media pipeline image in a modal dialog)
     */
    $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
```

Comment: It could be a possibility that wireshark didn't get the SDP/SIP info so it failed to decode the RTP automatically. Try using `Decode as...` to decode the UDP packets as RTP manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using WebRTC, the RTP stream is encrypted with DTLS/SRTP.
For this reason you are unable to see it in network traces such as Wireshark.

I am not sure if ffmpeg can decode them correctly.

You might try to use a WebRTC gateway to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the packet catched by wireshark and select "Decode As" option, and select decode as rtp. You will see the transmited packets by your webrtc app are srtp.